# How can I download the output of a RenderDataTable

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to figure out how to download a output from renderDataTable

```
special <- renderDataTable({
    data <- sessionvalues$data
    colnames(data) <- as.vector(sapply(colnames(data),idToName))
    action <- dataTableAjax(session, data,rownames = F)
    datatable(data, rownames = F,
              options = list(dom = 'itp',
                             ajax = list(url = action)))
  }, server = TRUE)

  output$table <- special()



  output$downLoad <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('Filtered data-', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep = '')
    },
    content = function(file){
      write.csv(special(),file)
    }
  )
```

and it shows `Error in special() : argument "shinysession" is missing, with no default`

any suggestions how to make this happen?

Comment: You can't write a data table to a csv. You probably want to use a `reactive` that returns the data frame to both your download handler and also to your renderDataTable.

Comment: would you like to show me how to do that? I am just a beginner of this, thanks a lot

Comment: The results of `renderDataTable` is a Shiny object, not really a table. Thus you cannot write it to a CSV.

Comment: is there has anyway to do that?

Comment: Since the output is just from `data`, isn't that you can just save your `sessionvalues$data` object?

Comment: i am so stupid, solved!! thanks a lot